# Are cryptozoology questions on-topic

Tags: discussion, scope

In a sense, many cryptozoology stories seem to be close to mythology - some have supernatural angle (yet, admittedly, not all or even not most). And the "real, ontopic" myths themselves are full of cryptids (Nemeian Lion? Ruuh bird? Phoenix?)

**Should cryptozoology stories (e.g. Nessie? Yeti? Chupacabra? etc...) be on-topic? If so, within what constraints?**

Comment: Sounds like part of folklore to me tbh.

Comment: [El'endia's meta answer defining mythology](http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/a/25/87) covers this, and I agree with what it says: Folklore about Nessie et al is fine, actual cryptozoology is not.

Answer (score 2):

Folklore and stories surrounding these creatures is on topic.

Attempts to actually find them, or prove their existence, in the natural world are not.